# How to make the labels readable by screen readers in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, screen-readers, accessibility

I am using accessibility scanner to check accessibility of my app.

It found that labels in my form are not readable by screen readers. I googled all day, but didn't find one example of how to do this. any help?
My form code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
    
    const MakemeAccessible= () => {
      const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('');
    
      return (
        <Text>Username</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
          value={value}
        />
      );
    }
    
    export default UselessTextInput;
```

[image: this item may not have a label readable by screen readers]

Answer (score 0):

use accessibilitylabel = "enter username" and accessible = "true" for  solving this kind of problem.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).